# Kinesis agent install in docker fails on missing mirrors

Tags: docker, centos7, amazon-kinesis-agent

I am trying to run a dockerfile that has worked for the past few months and since yesterday it started giving errors when using it on a new version of the same product.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER email@example.com

# Install PHP7
RUN yum install -y wget && \
    wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-8.noarch.rpm && \
    wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm && \
    rpm -Uvh remi-release-7*.rpm epel-release-7*.rpm && \
    rm remi-release-7*.rpm epel-release-7*.rpm && \
    sed -i '0,/enabled=0/s//enbaled=1/' /etc/yum.repos.d/remi-php70.repo && \
    yum -y update && yum install -y php

# Install other dependencies
RUN yum install -y httpd memcached mod_fcgid mod_ssl php-intl php-mbstring php-mysql php-pecl-memcache php-xml sendmail sendmail-cf m4

# Base configuration
RUN mkdir -p /StudyPortals/Deploy && \
    chown -R apache:apache /StudyPortals/Deploy && \
    mkdir -p /StudyPortals/Log/Apache2/httpd && \
    mkdir -p /StudyPortals/Log/Apache2/ServiceLayer && \
    mkdir -p /StudyPortals/Log/Apache2/VirtualHost && \
    mkdir -p /StudyPortals/Log/PHP7 && \
    mkdir -p /StudyPortals/Log/remote_syslog2 && \
    mkdir -p /StudyPortals/Log/Track/ && \
    chown -R apache:apache /StudyPortals/Log
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /StudyPortals/Log/Apache2
EXPOSE 80 443

# Configure sendmail
ADD config/Docker/Products/ServiceLayer/Applications/sendmail/ /etc/mail/
RUN sh -c 'makemap hash /etc/mail/genericstable < /etc/mail/genericstable && \
    m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf && \
    line=$(head -n 1 /etc/hosts) && echo "$line studyportals.com" >> /etc/hosts'

# Install and configure remote_syslog
ADD external/remote_syslog2/remote_syslog /usr/local/bin/
ADD config/Docker/Products/ServiceLayer/Applications/remote_syslog2/config.yml /etc/log_files.yml

# Install and configure Kinesis agent
RUN yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/streaming-data-agent/aws-kinesis-agent-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm
ADD config/Docker/Products/ServiceLayer/Applications/aws-kinesis-agent/agent.json /etc/aws-kinesis/agent.json

# Configure PHP
ADD config/Docker/Products/ServiceLayer/Applications/PHP7/ /etc/

# Configure Apache
ADD config/Docker/Products/ServiceLayer/Applications/Apache2/ /etc/httpd/
ADD external/ssl_certs_this_env /etc/httpd/conf.keys.d/

# Install product and config/install virtualhost
ADD source/ /StudyPortals/Deploy/ServiceLayer
RUN chown -R apache:apache /StudyPortals/Deploy/ServiceLayer/Data
ADD config/Docker/Products/ServiceLayer/VirtualHost/ /StudyPortals/Deploy/VirtualHost

# Start up
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
CMD ["line=$(head -n 1 /etc/hosts) && echo \"$line studyportals.com\" >> /etc/hosts && /usr/sbin/sendmail -bd -q1h && /usr/local/bin/remote_syslog --debug-log-cfg=/StudyPortals/Log/remote_syslog2/debug.log && /usr/sbin/apachectl -DFOREGROUND"]
```

It fails on the `RUN yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/streaming-data-agent/aws-kinesis-agent-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm` command.

This is my error output:

```
Step 12 : RUN yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/streaming-data-agent/aws-kinesis-agent-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm
 ---> Running in 56ef9169148e
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
[91mRepodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
[0mExamining /var/tmp/yum-root-bUQkDw/aws-kinesis-agent-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm: aws-kinesis-agent-1.1.2-1.amzn1.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-bUQkDw/aws-kinesis-agent-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package aws-kinesis-agent.noarch 0:1.1.2-1.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java >= 1:1.7.0 for package: aws-kinesis-agent-1.1.2-1.amzn1.noarch
[91mhttp://mirror.cuegee.de/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mTo address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please create a bug on https://bugs.centos.org/

[0m[91mhttp://ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.datente.com/media/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.daniel-jost.net/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.euserv.net/linux/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.intergenia.de/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://wftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.mirrors.psw.services/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.rackspeed.de/centos.org//7.2.1511/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.cuegee.de/centos/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.23media.de/centos/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.copahost.com/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://ftp.fau.de/centos/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centosmirror.netcup.net/centos/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.schlundtech.de/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://artfiles.org/centos.org/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://ftp.plusline.de/centos/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.euserv.net/linux/centos/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://wftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/centos/7.2.1511/extras/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.softaculous.com/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://repo.de.bigstepcloud.com/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.datente.com/media/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.intergenia.de/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.mirrors.psw.services/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.copahost.com/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://ftp.fau.de/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.euserv.net/linux/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttps://nl.mirror.babylon.network/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/cd31226c4d0df5b9471c307a59ee6857f9adf217c9c0684a3a92cef36febfba8-primary.sqlite.xz: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0mCould not retrieve mirrorlist http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php70/mirror error was
14: HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/safe/mirror error was
14: HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.euserv.net
 * epel: mirror.23media.de
 * extras: mirror.23media.de
 * remi-php70: mirror.23media.de
 * remi-safe: mirror.23media.de
 * updates: mirror.euserv.net
--> Processing Dependency: log4j for package: aws-kinesis-agent-1.1.2-1.amzn1.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 1:1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless = 1:1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjvm.so(SUNWprivate_1.1)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62(LIBJPEG_6.2)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjli.so(SUNWprivate_1.1)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjava.so(SUNWprivate_1.1)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9.0rc4)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libasound.so.2(ALSA_0.9)(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: fontconfig for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng15.so.15()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjvm.so()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjpeg.so.62()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjli.so()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjava.so()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgif.so.4()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libawt.so()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libasound.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXtst.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXrender.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXi.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXext.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
---> Package log4j.noarch 0:1.2.17-15.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec) for package: log4j-1.2.17-15.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mvn(javax.mail:mail) for package: log4j-1.2.17-15.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: jpackage-utils for package: log4j-1.2.17-15.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package alsa-lib.x86_64 0:1.0.28-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package fontconfig.x86_64 0:2.10.95-7.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: freetype for package: fontconfig-2.10.95-7.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: fontpackages-filesystem for package: fontconfig-2.10.95-7.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreetype.so.6()(64bit) for package: fontconfig-2.10.95-7.el7.x86_64
---> Package geronimo-jms.noarch 0:1.1.1-19.el7 will be installed
---> Package giflib.x86_64 0:4.1.6-9.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libSM.so.6()(64bit) for package: giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libICE.so.6()(64bit) for package: giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.x86_64
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless.x86_64 1:1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: tzdata-java >= 2015d for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lksctp-tools for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64
---> Package javamail.noarch 0:1.4.6-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package javapackages-tools.noarch 0:3.4.1-11.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-javapackages = 3.4.1-11.el7 for package: javapackages-tools-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch
---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.6.3-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libX11-common >= 1.6.3-2.el7 for package: libX11-1.6.3-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1()(64bit) for package: libX11-1.6.3-2.el7.x86_64
---> Package libXext.x86_64 0:1.3.3-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXi.x86_64 0:1.7.4-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXrender.x86_64 0:0.9.8-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXtst.x86_64 0:1.2.2-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libjpeg-turbo.x86_64 0:1.2.90-5.el7 will be installed
---> Package libpng.x86_64 2:1.5.13-7.el7_2 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-fonts-Type1.noarch 0:7.5-9.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: ttmkfdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: ttmkfdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mkfontdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: mkfontdir for package: xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fontpackages-filesystem.noarch 0:1.44-8.el7 will be installed
---> Package freetype.x86_64 0:2.4.11-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package libICE.x86_64 0:1.0.9-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libSM.x86_64 0:1.2.2-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libX11-common.noarch 0:1.6.3-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.11-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libxcb-1.11-4.el7.x86_64
---> Package lksctp-tools.x86_64 0:1.0.13-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package python-javapackages.noarch 0:3.4.1-11.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python-lxml for package: python-javapackages-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch
---> Package ttmkfdir.x86_64 0:3.0.9-42.el7 will be installed
---> Package tzdata-java.noarch 0:2016h-1.el7 will be installed
---> Package xorg-x11-font-utils.x86_64 1:7.5-20.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfontenc.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-20.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXfont.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-20.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.8-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libXfont.x86_64 0:1.5.1-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package libfontenc.x86_64 0:1.1.2-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package python-lxml.x86_64 0:3.2.1-4.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                     Arch   Version                 Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 aws-kinesis-agent           noarch 1.1.2-1.amzn1           /aws-kinesis-agent-latest.amzn1.noarch
                                                                           14 M
Installing for dependencies:
 alsa-lib                    x86_64 1.0.28-2.el7            base          391 k
 fontconfig                  x86_64 2.10.95-7.el7           base          228 k
 fontpackages-filesystem     noarch 1.44-8.el7              base          9.9 k
 freetype                    x86_64 2.4.11-11.el7           base          391 k
 geronimo-jms                noarch 1.1.1-19.el7            base           31 k
 giflib                      x86_64 4.1.6-9.el7             base           40 k
 java-1.8.0-openjdk          x86_64 1:1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2 updates       223 k
 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless x86_64 1:1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2 updates        31 M
 javamail                    noarch 1.4.6-8.el7             base          758 k
 javapackages-tools          noarch 3.4.1-11.el7            base           73 k
 libICE                      x86_64 1.0.9-2.el7             base           65 k
 libSM                       x86_64 1.2.2-2.el7             base           39 k
 libX11                      x86_64 1.6.3-2.el7             base          605 k
 libX11-common               noarch 1.6.3-2.el7             base          162 k
 libXau                      x86_64 1.0.8-2.1.el7           base           29 k
 libXext                     x86_64 1.3.3-3.el7             base           39 k
 libXfont                    x86_64 1.5.1-2.el7             base          150 k
 libXi                       x86_64 1.7.4-2.el7             base           40 k
 libXrender                  x86_64 0.9.8-2.1.el7           base           25 k
 libXtst                     x86_64 1.2.2-2.1.el7           base           20 k
 libfontenc                  x86_64 1.1.2-3.el7             base           30 k
 libjpeg-turbo               x86_64 1.2.90-5.el7            base          134 k
 libpng                      x86_64 2:1.5.13-7.el7_2        updates       213 k
 libxcb                      x86_64 1.11-4.el7              base          189 k
 lksctp-tools                x86_64 1.0.13-3.el7            base           87 k
 log4j                       noarch 1.2.17-15.el7           base          443 k
 python-javapackages         noarch 3.4.1-11.el7            base           31 k
 python-lxml                 x86_64 3.2.1-4.el7             base          758 k
 ttmkfdir                    x86_64 3.0.9-42.el7            base           48 k
 tzdata-java                 noarch 2016h-1.el7             updates       180 k
 xorg-x11-font-utils         x86_64 1:7.5-20.el7            base           87 k
 xorg-x11-fonts-Type1        noarch 7.5-9.el7               base          521 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+32 Dependent packages)

Total size: 51 M
Total download size: 37 M
Installed size: 132 M
Downloading packages:
[91mhttp://mirror.cuegee.de/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/alsa-lib-1.0.28-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
http://mirror.cuegee.de/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/fontconfig-2.10.95-7.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.cuegee.de/centos/7.2.1511/os/x86_64/Packages/fontpackages-filesystem-1.44-8.el7.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
```

That continuous with lots of mirrors that fail with 404

```
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.euserv.net/linux/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/Packages/java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://centos.intergenia.de/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/Packages/tzdata-java-2016h-1.el7.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.mirrors.psw.services/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/Packages/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
[0m[91mhttp://mirror.euserv.net/linux/centos/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/Packages/tzdata-java-2016h-1.el7.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
[0m[91mTrying other mirror.
[0m[91m

Error downloading packages:
  libXrender-0.9.8-2.1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  fontconfig-2.10.95-7.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  1:xorg-x11-font-utils-7.5-20.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libICE-1.0.9-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libSM-1.2.2-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libX11-common-1.6.3-2.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  alsa-lib-1.0.28-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  tzdata-java-2016h-1.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libXtst-1.2.2-2.1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  xorg-x11-fonts-Type1-7.5-9.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  2:libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libfontenc-1.1.2-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  python-lxml-3.2.1-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libX11-1.6.3-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libXext-1.3.3-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libjpeg-turbo-1.2.90-5.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  lksctp-tools-1.0.13-3.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.111-1.b15.el7_2.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libXfont-1.5.1-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  freetype-2.4.11-11.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libxcb-1.11-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  fontpackages-filesystem-1.44-8.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  ttmkfdir-3.0.9-42.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  javamail-1.4.6-8.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  log4j-1.2.17-15.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libXau-1.0.8-2.1.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  python-javapackages-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  geronimo-jms-1.1.1-19.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  libXi-1.7.4-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
  javapackages-tools-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/streaming-data-agent/aws-kinesis-agent-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have tried to add the `yum makecache fast` in front of the kinesis install the error suggests, but that didn't help

The https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623 link requires an active redhat subscription, so is also not helping.
The previous releases that use the exact same dockerfile still work but they are using cache.

```
Step 12 : RUN yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/streaming-data-agent/aws-kinesis-agent-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4e113ab6c52c
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: /enabled=0/s//enbaled=1/   => can't work, should prefer the "yum-config-manager --enable remi-php70" way

Comment: 7.2.1511 => should be 7 (to have all updates, current version being 7.3.1611)

Comment: @RemiCollet I don't specify the centos version to be anything other than 7, I don't know why it would try the 7.2.1511 mirrors

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was. The server that was running the build command somehow had a broken network interface that was not allowing correct NAT forwarding.

I solved it by stopping the docker deamon, removing the docker0 network interface and restarting the docker service.

```
pkill docker
iptables -t nat -F
ifconfig docker0 down
sudo service docker start
```